# Installer tries to resize my recovery partition instead of the normal partition when installing alongside Windows 7

Tags: partitioning, dual-boot, installation, ubiquity

When I try to install Ubuntu alongside Windows 7 (using the option in "install Ubuntu 11.10"), it tries to split with my recovery partition, not the proper Windows partition. If I try advanced settings, it shows that the amount of space used on the windows 7 partition is "unknown" and I cannot resize it.

If I try to make free space using Easeus Partition master on Windows 7 it "finds some error".

Chkdsk in windows found no errors.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Use tuxboot or unetbootin to create a bootable usb of gparted live or just use any ubuntu livecd installer and boot into it and select try ubuntu option,now use gparted partition editor to extend or modify the  partition on your system,the thing is that for any operation like extending etc have to be performed when the volume is offline.

you can download gparted live [here](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/download.php).there are also instructions to make a live cd/usb over there.

You can use easyBCD software to dual boot,please follow this [guide](http://neosmart.net/wiki/display/EBCD/Ubuntu)

Most of the times it will work,sometimes this may not work.In that case you can follow this [article](http://www.iceflatline.com/2009/09/how-to-dual-boot-windows-7-and-linux-using-bcdedit/).The second method is somewhat complex but it works for sure,I used both methods.

Comment: Interesting, because gparted through Ubuntu Livecd had the same issue i will still try a pure Gparted livecd

Comment: just tried livecd. Same issue. Exclamation mark next to Partition, won't let me size down (greyed out button)